# $|\hom(G, \Bbb Z/2)|>1 \iff |G:[G,G]|$ is even

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group. My problem is:
$$|\hom(G, \Bbb Z/2)|>1 \iff |G:[G,G]| \mbox{ is even}.$$

I know that $\hom(G, \Bbb Z/2)=\hom(G^{ab}, \Bbb Z/2)$, where $G^{ab}:=G/[G,G]$.
If $|\hom(G^{ab}, \Bbb Z/2)|>1$, there exists $f \in \hom(G^{ab}, \Bbb Z/2)$ and $|G^{ab}|=
|\ker f||\rm{im}~f|$. Since $f$ is nontrivial, $f$ needs to be onto i.e. $|\rm{im}~f|=2$. Hence $|G:[G,G]|$
is even.

Conversely, if $|G^{ab}|$ is even how can I prove that $|\hom(G^{ab}, \Bbb Z/2)|>1$?
I know $G^{ab}$ is abelian and contains an element of order $2$, say $x$.
From this can we find any nontrivial element of $\hom(G^{ab}, \Bbb Z/2)$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ be the abelianization and suppose that it contains an element of order $2$. It follows that the map $x\in G^{\mathrm{ab}}\mapsto 2x\in G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ has a non trivial kernel, so —since $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is finite— it is not surjective. The subgroup $2G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ of $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is therefore a proper subgroup. Now $H=G^{\mathrm{ab}}/2G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is non-trivial abelian group in which every element has order $2$. Such a thing is, in a canonical way, a vector space over the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Since $H\neq0$, from linear algebra we know that there is a non-zero linear map $H\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. The composition of that with the canonical projection $G^{\mathrm{ab}}\to H$ is non-zero, clearly.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see why the composition is a non-zero map.

Comment: Because it is the composition of a surjection with a non-zero map.

Comment: A linear map $H \to \Bbb Z/2$ is known as a linear functional. Any non-zero linear functional map is surjective. Then composite of surjections is surjection. Right?

Comment: I think it would be an another way to prove the problem if we can prove the composition $f \circ g$ is non-trivial where $f:G^{ab} \to S_n$ for some $n$ and $g:S_n \to \{-1,1\} \simeq \Bbb Z/2$. Do you think it will work?

Comment: I doubt anything will be gained.

Comment: Anw, I fully understand the problem, thanks to yours.